# Spring integration with http inbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Currently am working with spring integration with web service. I googled in many places including git but i could find good example to proceed with. I've configured the http inbound gateway and its not receiving the request from http client. Also am not sure what are the configuration needs to be added.
I couldn't find any better tutorial or steps to proceed. Any help much appreciated. Is it a good practice use http inbound gateway to receive http request as i couldn't find proper step or documentation to proceed.

Any help or guidance or example sites much appreciated.

Thanks,
Krish S

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing the problem, it would be better to share the config.

You can find more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/http.html).

Also you can take a look into the [Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/http).

Or even you can take a look into our Test Cases. For example [HTTP Proxy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-http/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/http/HttpProxyScenarioTests.java).

All that info are available from the main Spring Integration [site](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/).

Sorry for the bunch of links, but such a blurred leads to the common answer.